# Building an Amazon Affiliate product link with an 'linkId'?

Tags: joomla-extensions

I want to build a plug-in for Joomla where the webmaster simply specifies the ASIN number, and it builds the entire product link as is done at the Amazon Affiliate website. With creating so many links, it is time consuming to build them one at a time at the Amazon website.

I looked into this, and it looks like the only difference between the links it builds are the asin, at least it has been this way in the past, but the iframes it builds includes a 'linkId'. Which is a unique number. It is unique each time you use the build product link even though it is on the same ASIN.

How is Amazon generating this number? How can I generate it? I've looked in their Product Advertising API document and did a search for 'linkId' and it didn't find anything. I also can't find documentation about it anywhere else, just speculation that it is used in the Amazon Affiliate Reports, which is an important report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the 'linkId' is generated for internal use by Amazon and isn't a requirement for Amazon Affiliates. This might explain why it isn't mentioned in their documentation.